# Расшифровка паролей

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, пишу импорт паролей, требуется расшифровка

```
a35c745f1676903d3831353230372f2e3a343b37383b3a723a382f3b28343739383b283a723a383b38333d3831353218a1aa
```

тут зашифровано `admin`

На их сайте нашел алгоритм расшифровки, но у меня не выходит [алгоритм](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_protecting_credentials_for_automation)

вот как реализовал

```
string pass = "a35c745f1676903d3831353230372f2e3a343b37383b3a723a382f3b28343739383b283a723a383b38333d3831353218a1aa";
byte[] bytes = Enumerable.Range(0, pass.Length / 2).Select(x => Convert.ToByte(pass.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16)).ToArray();
byte[] decrypted = ProtectedData.Unprotect(bytes, null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
pass = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decrypted);
```

Прошу помочь, написав/исправив текущий алгоритм расшифровки

Answer (score 3):

Из [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dataprotectionscope(v=vs.110).aspx):

> `DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser`: The protected data is associated with the current user. Only threads running under the current user context can unprotect the data.

Это означает, что необходимая для расшифровки информация (вероятно, ключи) ключи хранится на машине пользователя в его профиле Windows. На другой машине или из-под другого пользователя расшифровать данные не удастся.

Пробуйте там же, где данные были зашифрованы.

Comment: Пробывал, не помогло